# Nativescript Angular: How do I bind other pages into a TabView?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to design a `TabView` like the one in https://www.nativescript.org/blog/guest-post-getting-cozy-with-nativescript's-tabview, just embed other "Pages" (`Component`), but I am using `naivescript-angular` so I cannot find any good tutorial for it. Any suggestion for doing so?

Comment: I have the same question. I want the tab view contents to be different pages and tabview to act like a menu bar. Can;t find how to do that using angular. I dont want to embed all html in one page. too complex

Answer (score 0):

I recommend researching the sample application from [this link](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng) and explore the tab-view examples [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ui-category/tab-view)

Comment: unfortunately those examples don't answer the question, they all keep the html code inside a single page, i'd like to have different tabviews in different pages.